# JSON.deserialize() for User records wont work

Tags: apex, json, user, compile-error, deserialize

I'm trying to deserialize a received user record on a JSON format. TO achieve this I'm using JSON.deserialize() but when I specify the User class the compiler throws the following error:

> Save Error: variable does not exist User.class

This is my code:

```
    @RemoteAction
    global static String updateTotalAccompByUserId(String userJSON, String userCategory, String totalAccomp, String currentQuarter, String currentYear){
        ...
        User user = (User) JSON.deserialize(userJSON, User.class); /*ERROR*/
        system.debug('%%% user: ' + user);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Usually such things happens when you have created a class with same name as object. In that case the compiler is confused.

Comment: No idea if it works, but did you try to use the `Type.forName('User')` alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue in my DEV org by creating a class named `User`.

Another class has following code:

```
User user = (User) JSON.deserialize('{}', User.class);
```

Which yeilds the same error as you have mentioned:

> Variable does not exist: User.class

Solution: Delete or rename `User` custom class and try again.

---

Better Solution mentioned by Adrain in comment: Use `Schema.User.class`:

```
Schema.User user = (Schema.User) JSON.deserialize('{}', Schema.User.class);
```

Comment: Better solution, use `Schema.User.class` instead.

Comment: Agreed. Naming a class with object is bad as it causes unnecessary problems in many places. If very much required I use inner wrapper classes instead of global ones.

Comment: No I 'm saying you don't need to delete the problem class, just be more explicit when declaring the type to deserialize into.